# Call YouTube AS3 API from AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a legacy application in AS2 that cannot be updated to AS3 right now. It was supporting the YouTube AS2 API, but Google just killed it, leaving only the AS3 API. Is there any way to make an AS3 swf using the Youtube API that can be called from my AS2 code so that I can continue to launch videos in my old app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, I don't think. One possible method off the top of my head is maybe make an AS3 wrapper around your AS2 swf (which would load it) and used a LocalConnection object to bridge them. If for some reason your AS2 is broken inside the AS3 wrapper (depending on how the AS2 is written), the AS3 'bit' could also be loaded as a separate flash element running beside the AS2 part (LocalConnection would still work).

Comment: I hadn't thought of as AS3 wrapper. I also thought I could put the js youtube code on my wrapper HTML and call that js from AS2. This would put the video on top of the flash, but it would work.

Comment: Oh, yea that can work too. It would make sense there that Google would also have a js version of the api (if it was running in a browser I'd probably do that instead).

Answer (score 1):

Google did not kill the AS2 API. It is still working and sure will in the future since there are a lot of companies using more AS2 then a lot of people expect because of the smoother encyrption possibilities. AS3 encryption often runs on False Positives with Antivirus and Malicious Detection Sites.

You just need to keep everything on a SSL (https) level and the YT AS2 API works perfectly fine.

Comment: Seriously? I'll try that. I can certainly run SSL by default. Thanks!